# ngIf my function error

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I am trying to display data from database. Then I want to verify for each data if it exists in another table, so I need to send a request for my back-office to check this data. Then I need to show if it's valid or not valid.

The problem is that `*ngIf` doesn't work and it shows me that my providers function doesn't work.

This is the HTML page:

```html
<ion-row *ngFor="let obj of listObj">
    <ion-col col-8>
        <ion-icon name="md-checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        <p>Objectif : {{obj.id_obj}} </p>
        <p id="nameobj"> {{obj.des_obj | titlecase}}</p>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4 *ngIf="testobj(obj.id_obj_ser).length">
        <p>lol</p>
        <!--
        <p id="valide">Vue</p>
        <p id="non-valide">Non Vue</p>-->
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This is my controller:

```js
export class ObjectifEnsPage {
    listObj = <[any]>[];
    testiObj = <[any]>[];
    id_stage: number;
    cin: number;
    test: boolean;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private etudiant: EtudiantProvider) {
        this.id_stage = this.navParams.get('stage');
        this.cin = this.navParams.get('cin');
        console.log("el stage w el cin ahawma" + this.id_stage, this.cin);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ObjectifEnsPage');
        this.getobjectif()
    }

    getobjectif() {
        this.etudiant.getobjectif(this.id_stage).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.listObj = data;
            console.log(data);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    testobj(id: number): any {
         this.etudiant.getobjectifvalidation(id, this.cin).subscribe((data: any) => {
             this.testiObj = data;
         }, error => {
             console.log(error);
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: But you are not returning a boolean, a truthy if you will from the method. It is an If condition, after all.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel it go to infinite loop on the testobject function

Comment: I think that your process is completely flipped around. You are probably experiencing this "infinite loop" because every time Angular fires off a change detection cycle your `testobj` function will run in that `*ngIf`. You are loading data and setting it on your object (via `this.testiObj` property) which will fire off another change detection cycle... thus getting your `testobj` function called. Can you provide you controller code so that we can try to help push you in another direction?

Comment: there it is , and what i want to do is to verify if the recieved data is not empty then the ngif work . @DanielWStrimpel

Answer (score 0):

You should return a `boolean` if you are using `*ngIf`
Your function should either return a boolean, or an Observable that resolves to a boolean

```
private testiObj$: Observable<any>;

testobj(id: number): any {
     this.testiObj$ = this.etudiant.getobjectifvalidation(id, this.cin);
```

and now you can subscribe to this in your template with the `async pipe`

```
<ion-col col-4 *ngIf="testobj(obj.id_obj_ser) | async">
```

As long as that Observable is returning a boolean.
Further reading:

https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe